# Controls synchronization between several threads in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have some controls on the form of the Windows Forms application and I need to update its' texts at run-time from several threads.

Is it safe to just call `BeginInvoke` method like this:

```
BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
{
    this.label.Text = "Some text";
});
```

from several threads at the same time? Should I do any additional synchronization in this case? Will it be processed by the same thread one by one and is this order guaranteed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `BeginInvoke` puts the delegate on to the message queue to be processed by the UI thread, it will process the queue handling the messages one by one. So no, you do not need to do any additional synchronization (as long as the delegate is not accessing any resources that can't be accessed from the UI thread).

As for order, it is not guaranteed they will be processed in order but in practice most of the time the delegates will be processed in the order they where put in to the queue.

---

To address the question in the comments, instead of using multiple `BeginInvoke` calls you should be able to get away with just one.

You never really explained what your animation was so I am going to assume it is going to be that `this.label` will swap between `.`, `..` and `...` then you store the result text in `this.label` when you are done.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        animationTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        animationTimer.Interval = 500;
        animationTimer.Tick += animationTimer_Tick;
    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer animationTimer;
    private int dots = 0;

    void animationTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Make 1, 2, or 3 dots show up. This runs on the UI thread so we don't need to invoke.
        this.label.Text = new String('.', dots + 1);

        //Add one then reset to 0 if we reach 3.
        dots += 1;
        dots = dots % 3;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        animationTimer.Start();
        Task.Run(() => DoSomeSlowCalcuation());
    }

    private void DoSomeSlowCalcuation()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            //We stop the timer before we set the text so the timer will not overwrite it.
            animationTimer.Stop();
            this.label.Text = "Some text";
        });
    }
}
```

This code is just a example to get my point across, if I where doing this I would use async/await for the button click and not use BeginInvoke at all.

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        animationTimer.Start();

        var result = await Task.Run(() => DoSomeSlowCalcuation());

        animationTimer.Stop();
        this.label.Text = result;
    }

    private string DoSomeSlowCalcuation()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        return "Some text";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another question about order -- what is the best practice to show "loading" animation and the result then? Is there any chance that the user will see the result before "loading" animation?

Comment: The best way to show a loading animation is you turn on the animation before you start the background work, once the work is done and you have a result you go back to the UI thread and stop the animation and show the result in the same function call. The UI won't repaint between the steps because you are on the UI thread so the user should never see a time where the animation is not running but the results are not available.

Comment: I already do it this way via `BeginInvoke` method call but as you said the order of this requests to the UI thread is not guaranteed and the code that shows "loading" animation may appear earlier than the results' representation, am I right?

Comment: @FrozenHeart see my updated answer with a detailed response to your comment.

Comment: Actually I need to set `DocumentText` property of the `WebBrowser` control with the "loading" gif, do some calculations and show the result in the same WebBrowser control

Comment: Ok, that does not change the logic at all. replace `animationTimer.Start();` with the code that sets the gif and `animationTimer.Stop(); this.label.Text = result;` with the code that removes the gif and sets the page content.

Comment: But as you said these actions can be processed by the UI thread in any order

Comment: Yes, multiple BeginInvoke could be in any order. **But I only used a single BeginInvoke**. The Gif would be set by the UI thread before you start the background thread then a single BeginInvoke would happen unsetting the gif and loading the content at a later point.

Comment: In my case it's impossible because I should start background thread from the COM event, not the UI thread. What can I do in this case?